# iOS Swift move app to background

Tags: ios, swift

I have an iOS application written in swift that leads the user through a series of questions. After the questions are finished, the app is done at this point. Later on an alarm will go off triggering the app to activate again. The issue is that I'm not sure how to exit the application once the questions are complete. I need to trigger the app to exit and go to the background. I've been fiddling around with an unwind segue but that doesn't go all the way back to exiting the app from what I've seen.

Can anybody give me a push in the right direction?

Answer (score 2):

You can only exit the app using a private API. You really shouldn't force a user out of your app.

Comment: Alright I've kinda seen that answer, guess it's the right one. I'm coming from Android and that seems really strange to me! I guess they'll just have to exit it.

Comment: I would display a "thank you" screen or similar that explains that they are done for now - possibly even with a count down timer that shows how long until they can return.  The user expectation in iOS is that they are in control of app switching. Suddenly exiting back to the Springboard will give the impression that your app has crashed.